# Regex gone Wrong

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am using a Bash script to use awk to look for this: `(0010,0080)` The awk will generally look for any numeric value seperated by a comma in between parenthesis. I have done everything I can think of and still can't get ANY results when I append it to a text file). My regex is:

`awk '/\([0-9]{4},[0-9]{4}\)/' dcmResults.txt >> ~/export/"$1"/tagResults.txt`

I have done almost every variation of using an escape character for the parenthesis including not using any and I get NO results when appending to a text file. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE, here is what the whole script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter SUID: "
read uid
echo "Enter Tag Number: "
read dicomTag

dicomDump() {
        arg1=$1
        cd ~/export/"$1"
        dcmdump *.dcm > ~/export/"$1"/dcmResults.txt
}
tagFinder() {
        arg1=$1
        arg2=$2
        for i in $(cat ~/export/"$1"/dcmResults.txt); do 
            grep "$2" | awk '/[0-9]{4},[0-9]{4}.*/' dcmResults.txt >> ~/export/"$1"/tagResults.txt
        break
done;
}
dicomDump "$uid"
tagFinder "$uid" "$dicomTag"
```

Comment: Works here (GNU Awk 4.1.1).

Comment: Can't see why it is not working for me. Might be the version of awk I am using....

Comment: I got GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: Let me post the whole script.

Comment: Not particularly, no

Comment: Only thing now is that it is not matching up with the specific value I feed it, I need it to only list that one value.

Comment: I must say, the whole script is a bit confusing to me. A `break` in the for loop without a condition? Unused value of `i` in the loop? Setting `arg1` and `arg2` but then using `$1` and `$2` anyway?

Comment: Sorry if it seems that way, Im not entirely sure how to use arg1 and arg2 with arguments in the functions with BASH scripting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnu Awk only started including interval expressions (your `{4}` qualifying the `[0-9]`) in 4.0:

> Interval expressions were not traditionally available in awk. They were added as part of the POSIX standard to make awk and egrep consistent with each other.
>
> Initially, because old programs may use ‘{’ and ‘}’ in regexp constants, gawk did not match interval expressions in regexps.
>
> However, beginning with version 4.0, gawk does match interval expressions by default. This is because compatibility with POSIX has become more important to most gawk users than compatibility with old programs.
>
> For programs that use ‘{’ and ‘}’ in regexp constants, it is good practice to always escape them with a backslash. Then the regexp constants are valid and work the way you want them to, using any version of awk.17

See [the manual entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html#Regexp-Operators).

Comment: Wow!!! Really?! lol

Comment: @ryekayo, for (some) lower versions of `awk`, you may be able to pass in `--re-interval` to enable support for `{` and `}'

Comment: I actually saw that in it's man page when I looked at it. Never occurred to me the version was why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

This line strikes me as having two problems:

```
grep "$2" | awk '/[0-9]{4},[0-9]{4}.*/' dcmResults.txt >> ~/export/"$1"/tagResults.txt
```

1. You can do the whole thing in `grep`:

   ```
   grep -e "$2" -e '([0-9]\{4\},[0-9]\{4\})' dcmResults.txt >> ~/export/"$1"/tagResults.txt
   ```
2. Where is `grep` getting its input, and where is the output of `grep` going to? Since `awk` has a filename for input, it would ignore standard input.